How to do a double indexer for an own class object in C#
I have done a new class to define a N-Dimensional Matrix in C#, however if I want to access to its elements and I dont know how to proceed more than 1 index. The elements are stored in an array of double arrays.
private class MatrixND
{
    private double[][] elements;
    public MatrixND()
    {
        elements = new double[N][];
    }
}

Usually, to access to the index in the own class I add the following method to the class:
public double this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        return elements[index];
    }
    set
    {
        elements[index] = value;
    }
}

Which would work if it was a simple array of doubles, then calling the index [i] where i can be any number from 0 to the lenght of the array, would return a double.
How I can do the same but for my matrix case so I can call mymatrix[index1][index2] and get a double?
Thank you very much!

Side note: double[,] may be more efficient if the data is rectangular.

Sorry if I missunderstood you, rectangular means same number of rows and columns? If so, for the actual case yes, but I would like to expand it to different number of columns and rows in the future.

Yes, rectangular here would mean that every row has the same length (or alternatively and equivalently: every column has the same height)

Just return a double[]  instead of just double from your indexer?

If you go the double[] route there don't forget to remove the setter of the indexer you don't need it.

What are going to do with mymatrix[index1][index2] ? Is it just a value or you intend to access mymatrix internals? Consider to return a wrapper from indexer, which takes current main instance and extend it with needed functionality, e.g. matrix[i] -> row, row[i] -> cell, etc.

@Ralf do you want to publish your answer? I will accept it since it was literally what I wanted! It turned out that I was almost there but I promise I didn't realize it was that obvious hehe

@Lluis i'm not on the hunt for reputation. I'm already happy that i could be of help.

Alright, then I will accept Marc's one and suggest to include your option, thank you again!

If you use public double this[int x, int y] then caller's can access obj[7, 12] etc. However, to access obj[7][12] would need the first indexer to return a type that itself has another indexer - maybe a struct that simply holds the parent instance and the first index value, effectively deferring the full lookup until the second index is supplied.

Something like:
public sealed class MatrixND
{
    private const int N = 42; // or a a.ctor arg, whatever
    private double[][] elements;
    public MatrixND()
    {
        elements = new double[N][];
    }

    public Indexer this[int x] => new(this, x);

    public readonly struct Indexer(MatrixND parent, int x)
    {
        public double this[int y]
        {
            get => parent.elements[x][y];
            set => parent.elements[x][y] = value;
        }
    }
}

